# Can I set default SSH options?

Tags: ssh

I'm talking about the client. I would like any SSH connection (including those done through SCP and gvfs, if possible) to use the option `ServerAliveInterval=30`

Is there somewhere that I can push this option to globally change how SSH connections are made?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aha. Well I just found `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` where I can put global settings. I've added

```
ServerAliveInterval 30
```

I'm not sure if this is going to change how gvfs and scp work though.

Comment: It should, as everything that uses SSH presumably calls the same code.

Comment: That's quite a presumption! I'll have a go at setting an option that should break ssh connection globally (later - have to work right now) and will update the answer to see if it does affect gvfs et al.